# Java 8 - usage of Consumer's andThen

Tags: java, java-8

I have below POC to  use Java 8 feature.

I want to update DB after accept method. Is it good to go with `andThen()`? When is this method called? Who calls it?

What is the basic use of `andThen()` method? Looking at the docs was confusing.

```
public class StockTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Trader> traders = new ArrayList<>();

    Random random = new Random();

    // Initializing trading a/c's.
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Trader trader = new Trader((random.nextInt(100) + 1) * 3);
        traders.add(trader);
    }
    // Display Trade accounts.
    System.out.println("Before Bonus, Units are:");
    for (Trader trader : traders) {
        System.out.print(trader.getUnits() + "\t");
    }

    // Add bonus to each trader.
    traders.forEach(new Consumer<Trader>() {

        @Override
        public void accept(Trader trader) {
            trader.updateBonus(2);
        }

        @Override
        public Consumer<Trader> andThen(Consumer<? super Trader> after) 
       {
            System.out.println("In andThen");
            return Consumer.super.andThen(after);
        }
        });

    // Display Trade accounts after bonus applied..
    System.out.println("\nAfter bonus:");
    for (Trader trader : traders) {
        System.out.print(trader.getUnits() + "\t");
     }

   }

 }

 class Trader {
    private int units;

    public Trader(int initialUnits) {
    this.units = initialUnits;
 }

   public int getUnits() {
        return units;
    }

public void setUnits(int units) {
    this.units = units;
}

 public void updateBonus(int bonusUnits) {
    this.units = this.units * bonusUnits;
  }
 }
```

Please help with some example or use cases to utilize this method

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In short andThen is used to chain consumers, so the input will go to first and second consumer, lke below:

```
Consumer<Trader> consumer1 = new Consumer<Trader>() {

    @Override
    public void accept(Trader trader) {
       trader.updateBonus(2);
    }
};

Consumer<Trader> consumer2 = new Consumer<Trader>() {

    @Override
    public void accept(Trader trader) {
       // do something
    }
};
// Add bonus to each trader.
traders.forEach(consumer1.andThen(consumer2));
```

So here the Trader will be passed to `consumer1`, then to `consumer2` and so on.

You don't have to implement this method, or override it. When it comes to Consumers, implement only the `accept`.

`andThen` method is a helper tool to join consumers. Instead of passing the input to all of them in a loop.

Answer (score 8):

You use `andThen` when you want to chain the logic of two `Consumer`s. `consumer1.andThen(consumer2)` first calls the `accept` method of `consumer1` and then calls the `accept` method of `consumer2`.

Overriding the default implementation of `andThen` makes little sense and prevents you from using lambda expressions/method references.

`andThen` can be used to chain two `Consumer`s:

```
traders.forEach(((Consumer<Trader>)(trader -> trader.updateBonus(2))).andThen(trader -> System.out.println("some more processing")));
```

Of course, in this example you can simply put the logic of the two `Consumer`s in a single `Consumer`:

```
traders.forEach(trader -> {trader.updateBonus(2);
                           System.out.println("some more processing");});
```

It makes more sense to use `andThen` when you are chaining two existing `Consumer`s:

```
Consumer<Trader> traderConsumer1 = trader -> trader.updateBonus(2);
Consumer<Trader> traderConsumer2 = trader -> System.out.println(trader);
traders.forEach(traderConsumer1.andThen(traderConsumer2));
```

Comment: You can’t just write `(trader -> trader.updateBonus(2)).andThen(trader -> System.out.println("some more processing"))`, as Java isn’t capable of inferring the type of the first lambda expression, hence, doesn’t know where to search for the `andThen` method, thus not being capable of determining the target type of the second lambda expression as well…

Comment: @Holger Yeah, I wasn't sure of that, and did test it. I guess you have to cast the first lambda expression to `Consumer<Trader>`. Thanks

Comment: One more reason to only use `andThen` when you have an existing consumer.

Comment: @Eran, Nice one. +1.